# How to group columns and show one of them only once in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to display information from a DNS Records, but only domains that have MX Records. By doing:

```
select name, content from records where type = 'MX';
```

I get:

```
domain1 | mx record 1
domain1 | mx record 2
domain1 | mx record 3
domain2 | mx record 1
domain2 | mx record 2
          ...etc
```

However, I need:

```
domain1 | mx record 1
          mx record 2
          mx record 3

domain2 | mx record 1
          mx record 2
          ...etc
```

How can I properly group this data to output the way I need?

Comment: You would have to process the results in your client-side code.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much!